# how to position 12 circles evenly in a big circle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

This is a realistic question in my study design needed to be solved. Please help.

In a 3-cm<sup>2</sup> big circle (area=3-cm<sup>2</sup>, so calculated radius of this big circle=9.77 mm), I need to put 12 small holes (all of same dimension). They should be evenly distributed with 4mm spacing from each other, and should be as close to the edge of the big circle as possible. How to position these small holes and how to calculate radius of the small holes?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really programming-related.  Try mathoverflow.com

Comment: it is programming related. programming is not just a language syntax or a set of technologies to master.

Comment: @bta: Really __don't__ try http://mathoverflow.com. Have you even seen that site? It's for crazy open maths research questions.

Comment: Agree with @Callum. I don't know if this is the most proper site (and I posted an answer), but I am sure mathoverflow isn't.

Answer (score 12):

Here you have three possible solutions based on different packings:

[image]

By the way, the [optimal packing](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/) for 12 circles is this:

[image]

Although they are not evenly distributed.

HTH!

Comment: Is it just me, or does the first diagram contain 13 circles?

Comment: @Bobby For 12 or 13 the hex pack is the same. The circle on the center is optional. Going to add that. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

start with placing them at the edge and proceed along a spiral towards the center. their radii depend on whether their proximity to the edge is more important than their size.

Comment: Size is not important as long as they are distributed evenly in the big circle and have 4-mm spacing. It is better to place some holes near the big circle edge, but firstly, they should be evenly distributed.
I had tried to put 8 holes at the edges (0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360 degrees). Add 4 near the center of the big circle, the center of each small circle form an equilateral triangle together with the centers of the other 2 small circles located at the big circle edge. But still I can not calculate the radius. Please help. Thanks

Comment: suppose you want to put two holes in to a circle. how would you do this to make them evenly distributed? i think your question is vague.

Comment: one more thing: the smaller circles can either be evenly distributed inside the bigger one or they can be as close as possible to the edges. your question says that they must be both.

Comment: How about if just one requirement: 12 smaller circles in a 3-cm2 big circle, with 4 mm spacing apart from nearby small circles?

Comment: i think the smaller circles should be packed as bee cells. i guess there is no more optimal solution. but i cannot prove this. this is a non-trivial problem to solve.